# Indexing Service Query Language returning more items than expected

Tags: pattern-matching, equals, indexing-service, dialect2

We're using [Indexing Service Query Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690538%28VS.85%29.aspx) (a.k.a. Dialect 2) and the following query,

```
@TaxCategory  "\Areas\Technology\" AND @XmlConfigId = 14
```

it unexpectedly matches the following two items instead of just the first:

```
Technology 
Technology, Media & Entertainment
```

We expected the ending slash would constrain the search to just that item; however it appears to grab anything having the given text at the beginning of the string.

**How do we write queries to target the first and second items independently?**

---

***Update:*** The content actually indexed by indexing service is this:

```
<ekttaxcategory>#eksep# \Areas\Technology #eksep#</ekttaxcategory>
```

and

```
<ekttaxcategory>#eksep# \Areas\Technology, Media & Entertainment#eksep#</ekttaxcategory>
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the substring `#eksep#` always appears at the end of what we're seeking, seen the example of indexed items in the question, we ended up solving the issue using this query:

```
@TaxCategory  "\Areas\Technology#eksep#" AND @XmlConfigId = 14
```

We also considered using [UNIX style pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690430%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the query and the period `.` as a string terminator, but never needed to try that after the above query worked.

If somebody else solves a similar problem using a different way or with pattern matching, please post another answer with sample query. Thanks.